# Is there a similar geometry node as Distribute Points on Faces for FILLING an object?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Two questions.

I am trying to get into geometry nodes. I started by doing a Blender Guru Beginner tutorial. At one point he is using Distribute Points on Faces on a cube, like you can see in the picture below.

1 - In this case, the cube is still hollow inside. I was wondering, is there also a node like this that actually fills the inside of the object? I want to basically create the same thing - an organic shape filled with 'random' spheres. So different sizes and colours.
I just don't know where to start.

2 - Do you also have some recommendations of where to start when learning about geometry nodes? I feel like a lot of tutorials are not explaining what certain nodes do or why use specific nodes. I mean I can just copy paste what they are doing, but I am not really learning anything from that or understanding why I am doing what I am doing.

Really appreciate your help! :)

[image]

Comment: There is a "distribute points in volume" node. Just remeber to put a mesh to volume node before that